# Should a CW "When will my device get Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0)?" be created?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, android-versions

Well, the title pretty much says it all, is it a good idea to create this in advance to reduce a flood of similar questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [When will my device get the Android 4.0 update (Ice Cream Sandwich)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14766/267)

I need a link to the official announcement, and a link to the updated Google Compatibility Guidelines would be useful, if someone wants to track that down.

Comment: I've added *an* official announcement, but the CDD doesn't exist yet from what I can see.

Comment: I don't think there will be a CDD since, like Honeycomb, ICS is closed-source. That's why the latest CDD is 2.3.3.

Comment: Then, assuming they follow through and open (like they say they will) a CDD will be published at that time?

Comment: @Al Everett That's what I'd expect, now the only question is when... I'm just impatient :)